# IE9 and Position Fixed

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to use the position fixed css on a simple one page website with vertical scrolling but am facing problems with IE9, it's like it's ignoring the fixed property, you can see the website here

http://cairocubicles.com/sandbox/mahaly-iphone/

looks right on chrome, firefox.

Appreciate the help.
Yehia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a doctype to make sure IE9 isn't going into quirks.

Comment: You can also check what mode IE9 (or 8) is in by opening the Developer Tools and checking the "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" (in the menu bar)

Comment: I was just about to make a hole in my screen, thanks @Graham_Clark

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure out.
I was writing some javascript using  which contained code to write to console.log. Never noticed it was a problem as i never use IE and nothing appeared to be broken in FF or chrome. I had the js above my  declaration and that was what was causing the error. you shouldnt put anything browser side before that declaration.