# Problem with IE position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I have this code it works quite well in Firefox; but shoots to the right on Explorer. Is there anything wrong with this code that I can't see?

Your help is appreciated

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 170px"><a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="images/sponsor.png" /></a></div>
```

What I'm expecting is for the image to show on top of the main header image- which works alright on Firefox, but moves to the far right in IE causing the site to break. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Try adding `left: 0px;` as well, maybe in IE it won't give it such default value..

Comment: Cheers, I've also added it as answer now.. didn't expect it to be so simple lol. By the way, when using `@` don't replace space with `-` just omit the space e.g. `@shadowwizard` but even better, you can use only the first three letters e.g. `@sha` or more "friendly" but still short `@shadow` :)

Comment: If you're asking about IE7, then fine. If it's a more recent version of IE, you have [a worse problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472491/positionfixed-breaks-in-ie9/7472595#7472595). Even if it is IE7, Quirks Mode is still no good.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `left: 0px;` as well, IE probably won't give it such default value:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 0px;">
```

Answer (score -2):

I found out that IE won't recognize properties declared like :

```
top:(space)20px;
```

- so if you have a space between  `:` and `20px` IE will ignore that property. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Could you please expand from which source you got this info?
Is't only for this property or for all css properties?