# Relative div inside an Absolute div

Tags: html, css

Consider The Following case,

```
   <div id="d1" style="position:relative">
    <div id="d2" style="position:absolute">
     <div id="d3" style="position:absolute">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

By Referring the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928059/absolute-positioning-inside-absolute-position), 
 I Just confirmed that the `<div id="d3">` will be relative to the `<div id="d2">`.
Even if we given position as absolute for `<div id="d2">`. 
Similarly what would it assumes when we place `<div>`s like below? (relative `<div>` inside a absolute `<div>`)

```
   <div id="d1" style="position:relative">
    <div id="d2" style="position:absolute">
     <div id="d3" style="position:relative">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

can anybody explain this.?

Comment: I would assume that it behaves like a `relative` div inside any other div. What's your question exactly?

Comment: d3 must be relative to d2, because the definition says it's an absolute positioning, relative to the first non-static parent. For your second example, there is nothing to assume, it is just a relative positioned div in an absolute positioned div. Nothing special there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would expect the `relative` div `d3` to maintain position relative to it's parent.  See [W3 Specification for Css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comparison) for more information on how things *should* be positioned.

I emphasise *should* as there are quirks within individual browsers for the box model that may have an impact on this.

See the [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NsqrB/2/) for a quick demo of this.

Comment: Which browsers have what quirks about this? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @Rob IE 6/7 are always a special case and may require additional attention - Things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499538/problem-with-ie-position-absolute

Answer (score 3):

Given the html/markup

```
 <div id="d1" style="position:relative">
  <div id="d2" style="position:absolute">
   <div id="d3" style="position:relative">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

div#d1

- div#d1 will remain in the normal flow of the document.
- div#d1 has no offset properties (Top, Right, Bottom, Left) and therefore will remain exactly where it is. i.e. it's position will be such as if no position: relative is applied to it.
- div#d1 wil act as a new positioning context for div#d2.

div#d2

- div#d2 will be taken out of the normal flow of the document.
- div#d2 will be positioned relative to div#d1.

div#d3

- div#d3 will remain in the normal flow of the document but it's flow is determined now by div#d2.

[Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kami said, `div#d3` should be relative to its parent, and is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ezcV/) -- I put together a jsFiddle to explain better, and so you can play with different results.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ezcV/