# jQuery UI Dialog not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI 1.8.19 and Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.3 in a site I'm developing. I want to show a modal dialog when click in a Delete and for this I do that:

```
 <div id="dialog-confirm" title="<?php echo lang("event:delete_confirm_title") ?>">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span><?php echo lang('event:delete_confirm_content') ?></p>
 </div>
```

And the JS to fire the event is this one:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "<?php echo lang('event:delete') ?>": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "<?php echo lang('global:cancel_label') ?>": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For some reason the modal dialog is always showed at the end of the page when it shouldn't be I think and when I click the  element the dialog appears but the page is redirected instantaneously to my home page and didn't know the cause because I don't have redirects in any place and also there are no forms there. Any advice or help on this?
Best regards

Comment: any chance a link you could post? i could prolly help trubl shoot this pretty quick if you have it online somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `style='display: none'` to your dialog div so it won't be displayed at startup.

Then if the page is sent to home when you click the button, you may want to check what type of button #delete is and finish it's function with `return false`if it's a Submit for example to avoid normal click event handler to be launched :

```
$(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(e){
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "<?php echo lang('event:delete') ?>": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "<?php echo lang('global:cancel_label') ?>": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Edit : Modification done according to Scott suggestion

Comment: Nice Michael, maybe the page was send because I not write the "return false" now it's not send any. Also I fix the style:"display:none" and the DIV isn't showed until I click the button which is not a button just a HREF styled as a button using Twitter Bootstrap. Many thanks and all the points to you!!

Comment: I would probably pass `e` into the function and call `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the click action instead of `return false` as it also calls `e.stopPropogation();` which prevents other events from bubbling up.

Comment: Hmm could you post a sample @Scott

Comment: Simply replace `$("#delete").click(function(){` with `$("#delete").click(function(e){` and `return false;` with `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Nice, added to my code in order to improve it!! Many thanks @Scott

Comment: @Scott Code modified to follow your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. There is only one cause I know of. The dialog CSS file is not being loaded.

See my SO Question: [position:fixed breaks in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472491/positionfixed-breaks-in-ie9)