# IE9 clips fixed child of absolute border-radius

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Here's a JSFiddle that breaks uniquely in Internet Explorer 9. I'm hoping someone has seen this and knows how to resolve it.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/se9Kc/1/

Note that the scroll area top edge decoration, or "fader", gets clipped on the right side in IE9.

I understand it's natural to question the use of "fixed" at this point. The full page has an inset scrolling table with an absolutely-positioned header, adjacent to the search criteria. The "fader" is anchored to its non-scrolled (but still fluidly-generated) origin with position: fixed.

The defective algorithm seems to go like this:

1. correctly generate the visibility mask and content for the fixed element
2. correctly position the element content as requested
3. incorrectly position the element visibility mask against the left edge

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of testing, it seems like using javascript to handle that particular css property allows it to function properly.

Remove:

```
position: fixed;
```

and add somewhere on your page:

```
<script>    
    $(.fadeTopGradient).css({'position':'fixed'})
</script>
```

If you would like accomplish this with css alone, I'm not 100% sure what to tell you. Though I did see a question regarding position:fixed in IE9 asked before here: [position:fixed breaks in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472491/positionfixed-breaks-in-ie9)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm alright with a hack like this. Using JavaScript to add a CSS constant property is not as egregious as, say, using it to maintain position and width as the document size varies. That always leads to defects later. Although I'm curious how you discovered this fix. That's crazy :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you out! The fix itself is something I came upon when messing around with opacity as a CSS property a while ago. Because some properties are not fully understood on all browsers, it takes a lot of writing (adding -moz-, -webkit-, etc, before opacity:0.5, for instance). It's like giving out Spanish, French, and English instructions in a manual. 

However, Javascript is like sign language to browsers. They all get it. If you're having issues with browsers displaying properties differently, try using javascript instead. Works most of the time.

Comment: So it looks like it's render order again, a matter of when the position is calculated, which is why using javascript fixes this. I need "fixed" for IE7, can't have it for IE9, and neither works right. Isn't 15 years of getting the browser wrong enough?