# jQuery - have popup box appear on screen regardless of how low they scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a popup box on a list of items that goes very much to the bottom of the browser.

**I want the POPUP to be in the center of the page where the user is at regardless of how low they scrolled**

i have to use POSITION ABSOLUTE not FIXED

but when i use POSITION ABSOLUTE the popup always appears on top and i know its due to my top: 0

```
.lightbox-container{
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 }
```

I want to use something like scrollTop or one of those to get the popup to always stay in the users viewpoint regardless of how low they scrolled

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  var lightBox = $('<div class="lightbox-container"> <p>click to remove</p>');
  lightBox.appendTo('body');
  $('.lightbox-container').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

here is the fiddle im working on http://jsfiddle.net/2RNAN/1/

I know there are other posts about this but im very new to jquery and cant seem to get it working.

Comment: For anyone coming here from Google, using `position: fixed` on the element will achieve this. The OP explicitly stated they cannot do this, but it is the cleanest solution to someone who does not have that constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be a little late but I think this might be closer to what you were after:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kCC8p/6/)

```
$(function () {
    var lightbox = $('.lightbox-container'),
        center = function () {
            var T = $(window).height() / 2 - lightbox.height() / 2 + $(window).scrollTop(),
                L = $(window).width() / 2 - lightbox.width() / 2;
            lightbox.css({
                top: T,
                left: L
            }).click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        };

    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        lightbox.show().text('Click to remove');
        center();
    });
    $(window).scroll(center);
    $(window).resize(center);
});
```

Note that this method centers the popup and keeps it centered regardless of scrolling or re-sizing.

Comment: @RickyAhn Glad to help, do you understand how it works or do you need links to the documentation?

Comment: i know enought about the methods used to get an understanding of whats going on.....i will spend some time and study your code....thanks!

Comment: Good example, but I mentioned 1 bug, when I scroll to the bottom of the screen it drop downs by 1px and when I go to the top of the screen it ups in 1px... what can be a problem with it ?

Comment: @user1139767 not sure what you're seeing, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using FF 28.0 mac version

Answer (score 4):

This works working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/kCC8p/4/)

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lightBox = $('<div class="lightbox-container"> <p>click to remove</p>');
    lightBox.appendTo('body');
    $('.lightbox-container').css('top', $(document).scrollTop() + 'px');
    $('.lightbox-container').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.lightbox-container').css('top', $(document).scrollTop() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Rob, your solution is elegant but doesn't work for me. In the jsFiddle, if I click on the bottom `Click Me` link, the lightbox still appears at the very top of the page. *Only when I begin to scroll up* does the lightbox suddenly jump down to the top of the view port.

Comment: I have fixed the code as you mentioned to automatically adjust based on current scroll-state when the lightbox is shown.

Comment: Good job. I can +1 your answer now. Thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I think its a bit unclean and also unnecessary to center the pop-up box via jQuery. You can easily do this with CSS. Check out my updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kCC8p/9/ **Edit End**

I set the overflow to hidden on the body and included the pop-up **outside** the scrollable element. This way the scroll position of the user doesn't matter anymore.

JS

```
var lightbox = $('.lightbox-container');

$('a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
lightbox.show();
lightbox.addClass('open');
lightbox.append('<p>Click to remove</p>'); 
});

lightbox.click(function(e) {
    lightbox.removeClass('open');
    lightbox.find('p').remove(); 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

See rest on jFiddle...

Comment: Another nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you avoiding the use of position fixed due to IE9 compatibility or some other reason?  Using position fixed is probably the simplest answer and then address whatever compatibility issue you're having with specific browsers, such as with [this answer for IE9 regarding quirks mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694517/ie9-and-position-fixed)